# Unable to upload the LDS 2.10.0 as static resource

Tags: lightning, css, lightning-design-system, static-resources

As we know that static resource has a limit of 5MB, I am trying to upload the LDS winter 20  as static resource, but its size is more than 5 MB

https://lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/

In this link I downloaded the one which needs to be used as static resource Lightning Design System Static Resource, being the size is more than 5MB i am unable to upload.

Any idea how do I upload that ?

Comment: As per [Salesforce Document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources.htm&type=5) single upload, static is 5mb and org wise 250mb which you can increase to raise a request to salesforce. Try to upload with zip format.

Comment: Its the zip format only I am downloading from this link https://lightningdesignsystem.com/downloads/ . The one named as ''Download Lightning Design System (Static Resource) (2.10.0)

Comment: Also I am uploading a single static resource and my org has not reached to the limit of 250MB . While uploading the file from the download url it says Error: static resource cannot exceed 5MB

Comment: yeah that's fine, but you can't upload single static resource more than 5mb, try to upload multiple static resources. By the  way, why are you uploading Lightning Design System as a static resource, As salesforce lightning inbuild `slds` CSS classes.

Comment: @Sarvesh: Yes salesforce inbuild slds class but in my org for the existing aura components, The static resource is being referred, I tried removing it but then the UI breaks completely so I am planning to upload the new LDS.

Comment: Also If I upload multiple static resource how the main salesforce-design-system.css will refer the fonts and other stuffs, If you open the css file In the single static resource the fonts , images are getting refferred

Comment: Below is the css file for your refernce                                                                        /*! Lightning Design System 2.10.0 */
@charset "UTF-8";@font-face{font-family:'Salesforce Sans';src:url(../fonts/webfonts/SalesforceSans-Light.woff2) format("woff2"),url(../fonts/webfonts/SalesforceSans-Light.woff) format("woff");font-weight:300;font-display:swap}@font-face{font-family:'Salesforce Sans';src:url(../fonts/webfonts/SalesforceSans-LightItalic.woff2) format("woff2"),url(../fonts/webfonts/SalesforceSans-LightItalic.woff)

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading the SLDS files to support Visualforce development, such as creating a Visualforce Page (VFP) for a Force.com Site, you can just reference the SLDS tag in the VFP:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:slds />
    // addition page apex/html markup
</apex:page>
```

Check out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_slds.htm